# Is there a way to copy text in htop on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, terminal.app, htop

I wanted to copy all of the process information related to a specific program/software (Adobe in this case, other ones in the future) and so I tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as mentioned here:

[Is there a way to copy text in htop?](https://superuser.com/questions/809989/is-there-a-way-to-copy-text-in-htop)

but this does not seem to work in Mac OSX terminal.

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Instructions:

1. Try using `top` instead of `htop`. The `-l1` flag will provide a static output.
2. Pipe to `grep`; or use the mouse; to isolate / extract a particular process. (Optional).
3. Pipe the output directly into `pbcopy`; or use the mouse; or <kbd>⌘C</kbd>; to copy.
4. Use `pbpaste`; or the mouse; or <kbd>⌘V</kbd>; to paste the captured output.

---

### Code:

```
tjt263@osx:~$ top -l1 |grep -i adobe
86284- Adobe Flash Play 0.0  00:01.36 3     0   142+   24K+   0B   19M+   86284 1     sleeping *0[78+]       0.00000 0.00000    501 11281+     531+     2380+       867+        5758+       3320+       4770+       1993+    1        0.0   tjt263          N/A    N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A  

tjt263@osx:~$ top -l1 |grep -i adobe |pbcopy 

tjt263@osx:~$ pbpaste
86284- Adobe Flash Play 0.0  00:01.36 3     0   142+   24K+   0B   19M+   86284 1     sleeping *0[78+]       0.00000 0.00000    501 11281+     531+     2380+       867+        5758+       3320+       4770+       1993+    1        0.0   tjt263          N/A    N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
```

---

### Screenshots:

*In case this is confusing for you;

I have provided some cropped screenshots:*

[image: head]
[image: tail]

Answer (score 3):

Try holding <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd> while selecting.

Comment: This is perfect for more freedom selecting information and it is good for general freeform stuff. tjt263's solution is the more programmatically solid solution I was seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Click with a mouse anywhere in the Terminal window.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all text in the window.

Before the next refresh press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy all text.

Paste to a text editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and edit out unnecessary information.

Comment: Thanks! This does work but it is the longer/harder way to do it. tjt263's solution is the more programmatically solid solution I was looking for.