# Copy text from htop with long line

Tags: linux, terminal, htop

related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/809989/is-there-a-way-to-copy-text-in-htop?newreg=15b974aa323d4a3a99d54c9af98989b7), I want to inspect a command listed in `htop`, but the command is very long. Therefore the suggested anwer to select text while holding shift does not work as it does not select somthing that overflows to the right of the screen. Is there any help provided by htop to extract the selected line somehow?

Comment: You want to take a note of the pid in htop, then grep for it using ps aux | grep <pid>

Comment: Read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1326752/432690); note `/proc/$pid/cmdline`.

Answer (score 0):

If the command trails off-screen then I'm not aware of a way to copy that text using the mouse, even with using shift. However, you could try:

***Optimizing your htop display to reveal the command(s)***

**Option 1:** Within htop, hit `F2`(if you're on a laptop, that may need to be `function+F2`), you'll be in the setup menu. Use the arrow keys to scroll down to `Columns` then hit right to move over to the columns in view. If not all of these columns are useful to you, you can remove some of them with `F9`(again, that may be `function+F9`). You can exit back to regular view with `ESC` and you should see more if not all of the command(s).

**Option 2:** Within that same setup menu(`F2`), go to `Display options` and uncheck the `Show program path` option with the `Enter` key, then hit `ESC` to exit. This may further reduce the size of the process so it is rendered inspect-able. Once you get the command, if you need the full path, you can just run `which <command>` in the terminal.

---

**Important Note:** If you make changes to your htop setup, you can discard them by quitting the program with `CTRL+C`. If you want to save those changes, quit the program with `F10` or `q` (See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147885/how-can-i-set-default-settings-for-htop) for more detail).

**Speculation:** Depending on what you want to achieve by inspecting that command, you may be able to achieve it right from htop, which allows you to kill a program(highlight and press `F9`), change its Niceness(highlight and press `F7` to decrease or `F8` to increase), and lots of other stuff. See [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/) and [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/power-user-guide-htop/) for more examples.